# Including AOSP classes in my app

Tags: android, class, include, android-source

I made a custom class that extends ProgressBar for some extra functionality. It's all functioning but I found that there is a difference in the way it displays on different phones with different ROMs.

For instance, it works flawlessly on the Android emulator but it's kinda messed up on my actual phone which runs MIUI ROM but runs fine on my old HTC with Cyanogen. I figured it's because MIUI has it's own custom ProgressBar class, among other custom widget classes made by them to give the ROM a different look.

I want to know if there is a way to include the 2.3.3 AOSP ProgressBar class in my app so that it overrides the class already present on the phone of the user, regardless of the custom ROM of the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the ProgressBar source code from AOSP and change the package name from it. This may have some problems though.

1. You'll have to reference it by the full package name + class name
   when using it in XML layouts.
2. Copying the code over isn't trivial.
   You'll have to fix the compile errors as you see them. Perhaps
   create reflection hooks for private variables and so on.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought I needed to do. I've copied over the AOSP source code inside my class that extends ProgressBar. Gave me tons of errors of missing variables and whatnot. I don't care if I have to use the full package name for layouts, I already did that for my extended class. I guess I'll have to troubleshoot all those errors.